# How to avoid printing same number twice when printing values between 2 digits

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

Newbie to Java, have an assignment for practice. We are trying to print all values between 1 and 100 that are divisible by 5 or 7. However, there are values that are divisible by 5 AND 7 that will print twice. Simplest way to avoid repeating numbers?

```
    int sum  = 0;
    
    i=1;        
     
    while (i <= 100)
    {
        //need to update the value of sum by i
        //sum = sum + i;
        
        
        /*if( i % 5 == 0 || i % 7 ==0 ) //if i is  divisible by 5 or 7, let us display i
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            
        }*/
        
        if ( i % 5 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        
        }   
        if ( i % 7 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        
        }
        
        if ( i % 5 == 0 || i % 7 == 0)
        {
            
            sum = sum + i;
        
        }
        
        
        
        //if ( i %
        
        i=i+1;      
        
    
    }
    //also print the total of the numbers being displayed
    
    int add;
    System.out.println("the sum is: " + sum);
    
    System.out.println("Bye, for now!");
```

Comment: ** if ( i % 5 == 0 || i % 7 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            sum = sum + i;
        
        } ** Just remove first to if

Comment: This is also called the fizz buzz problem, you can find lots of solutions, some overly clever, if you search for that.

Answer (score 1):

Using && operator to print the repeating numbers once and conditional operators to do the rest of the logic will help eventually.

Try this code

```
int sum  = 0;
    
int i=1;        
     
    while (i <= 100)
    {
        
         if ( i % 5 == 0 && i % 7 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            sum += i;
        
        }
        
        else if ( i % 5 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            sum += i;
        
        }   
        else if ( i % 7 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            sum += i;
        
        }
        
      
        
        i++;      
        
    
    }

    //also print the total of the numbers being displayed
    
    System.out.println("the sum is: " + sum);
    
    System.out.println("Bye, for now!");
```